# Get the latest file in every directory using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I want find the latest zip file in every directory in a current working directory. I have this code that can find the latest file in one folder:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*.zip') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print latest_file
```

How can I find the latest file in all folders?

Comment: what do you mean by *"all folders"*? Like all all?

Comment: Like an example if I have a current working directory with 5 folders and each folder has its own files.

Comment: `os.listdir` will list all files and folders, can call it recursively

Answer (score 4):

**Python 3.5+**:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/**/*.zip', recursive=True)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

Quoting the documentation for [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

> If recursive is true, the pattern `**` will match any files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by an os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match.

---

For old versions:

**Python 2.2+:**

```
import fnmatch
import os

list_of_files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.zip'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print latest_file
```

Comment: I tried to run the python 2.2+ example, but it's giving an error saying that max () arg is an empty sequence.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Are you positive that there are some zip files in the said directories?

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't comment, the previous answer should read:

**Python 2.2+:**

```
import fnmatch
import os

list_of_files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.zip'):
        list_of_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print latest_file
```